# Executing a command as apache

Tags: apache-2.2, sudo, exec

This script keeps outputting a `1`. and I cannot understand why.

```
<?php
        passthru("nohup sudo rndc reload sd.example.com",$op);
        print_r($op);
?>
```

I have also tried the above code without the `nohup`. I have the following line in my sudoers file

```
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/rndc reload sd.example.com
```

Just to test, temporally, I allowed apache a shell, logged in as apache by `sudo su apache` and successfully managed to execute `sudo rndc reload sd.example.com`. I have been restarting httpd each time I made changes to the sudoers file.

I do not see any error message in my log files wither. What could I be possibly doing wrong? None of the similar threads have pointed me to anything that solved my problem or debug it.

Comment: Did you look at the sudo logs or only the apache logs?

Comment: I was only looking at the Apache Logs. I did not even have a sudo log. Once I configured sudo to start logging, I saw the error - `sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo @ sudoers_policy_main()`. I had faced this error before, except that time I had seen this show up in apache error logs. once I made an exception for apache to be ale to run without a tty, the above script worked.

@JennyD - Thanks for that pointer :-)

Comment: Glad I could help!